# kraftwagen is not working

Tags: linux, drupal, drupal-7, drush

I'm trying to do setting a kraftwagen project using http://kraftwagen.org/get-started.html

I can go through the document until Building topic. But after that, when I try to run `drush kw-b` is it give some error.

```
$ drush kw-b
Makefile generated from template (/home/dinuka/drush_test/src/tools/build.make.tpl).[success]
Beginning to build /tmp/kwLL5uil.                                                        [ok]
drupal-7.22 downloaded.                                                                  [ok]
file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given filesystem.inc:185      [warning]
Source directory p is not readable or does not exist.                                 [error]
drush_test copied from p.                                                                [ok]
Called command make returned an error.
```

I can't find drupal-7.22 anywhere. I think it is a problem. I'm a newcomer to Drupal and these things.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! If this is still an issue, could you share your `tools/build.make.tpl` with us?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me to be a bug, like this one : https://drupal.org/node/1078318

Maybe you should report it directly (and try to get the patch for it.)

Hope it helps! :)